# Set a time for the for loop

Tags: c, pic

I want to define timing in a for loop:

```
int count;
int forfunctime;
for(count=0;count<5;count++)
{
    output_b(sutun[count]);
    output_c(UC[count]);
    delay_ms(1);
}
```

```
int count;
int forfunctime;
for(forfunctime=0;forfunctime<100;++forfunctime)
{
    for(count=0;count<5;count++)
    {
        output_b(sutun[count]);
        output_c(UC[count]);
        delay_ms(1);
    }
}
```

In the SECOND code I am able to get a delay using the MIPS instruction processing time by enclosing the for loop but is there a more precise way?

My goal is to set a time for the for loop.
edit: for those who will use this information later: While programming PIC, we use a for loop to scroll the row and column in matrix displays, but if we want to keep this loop active for a certain period of time, we need to use timers for this.

Comment: Huh?  I do not understand the question.

Comment: Delays in embedded are usually not the way forward. Try reading a time-based value such as with `time()` or `clock()` to see how much time has elapsed.

Comment: I want to run the for loop written in the first code for 10 seconds. @OldProgrammer

Comment: ...and if your C implementation doesn't support them, make a regular 'heartbeat' interrupt from a timer which maintains some 'tick' counter. In the embedded projects I work on (with no OS), I would implement that as one of the first jobs, but if you have a function `delay_ms` there is hopefully something already like that for you (and not a software delay loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I dont't know which PIC you're using, I can't answer precisely to this question, but I can draw you the general map.

What you need is a timer. There are timers on almost every microcontroller. But it is very likely that you will have to manually program it, generally by settings some bits in memory. [Here](https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/PIC16f877a_Timer) is an example on how to program a timer.

The first and most naive solution is to set one of your microcontroller's timer and read it's value each time you're out of your loop, like below :

```
setTimer(); //Your work, not a predifined function
while (readTimer() < yourTimeConstant){ //againt, your work, not a predifined function
    for(count=0;count<5;count++){
            output_b(sutun[count]);
            output_c(UC[count]);  
            }
     }
```

The second and cleaner solution would be to use events if your microcontroller supports them.

Comment: Peripheral Features:
• Timer0: 8-bit timer/counter with 8-bit prescaler
• Timer1: 16-bit timer/counter with prescaler,
can be incremented during Sleep via external
crystal/clock
• Timer2: 8-bit timer/counter with 8-bit period
register, prescaler and postscaler

Comment: @electronx seems like it is exactly the one in the link I gave in my answer then

Comment: @electronx I highly suggest to use the 16-bits one, since the 8-bits ones will overflow before 10s

Comment: Since you're using a timer, there's probably no need for the call to `delay_ms(1)`.

Comment: @Caleb you’re absolutely right, I edited it

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current time just before enter the loop and check if already passed 10 seconds at every loop iteration, but actually that isn't the best way to do that. If you're working on windows system check [waitable timer objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects), for linux check [alarm](https://linux.die.net/man/3/alarm)

Comment: OP's working on a pic, there is very little chance that it has an OS

Comment: @TUIlover right, so maybe the best solution is working with time.h library using the ```clock()``` function and check if the time passed at every loop iteration ?

Comment: Not all microcontrollers support timer.h

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run the for loop written in the first code for 10 seconds.

Microcontrollers generally provide timers that you can use instead of delay loops. Timers have at least two advantages: 1) they make it easy to wait a specific amount of time, and 2) unlike `delay` functions, they don't prevent the controller from doing other things. With a timer, you can pretty much say "let me know when 10 seconds have passed."

Check the docs for your particular chip to see what timers are available and  how to use them, but [here's a good overview of how to use timers on PIC controllers](http://picguides.com/beginner/timers.php).